# I'm practicing for/while loops. Ran into a string indexing error

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, range

```
    def onlyLetters(seq):
        seq = seq.lower()
        letter = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'z')
        for i in range(len(seq)): 
             if seq[i] != letter: 
                  seq = seq[:i] + seq[i+1:]
        return seq
```

I'm trying to make a for loop that iterates over all elements of the string seq, and check if it matches the tuple letter (I will fill it in with all letters of the alphabet later) and if it doesn't then I will redefine the string seq by slicing out the ith element which did not match the tuple. I want to take a string like 'Hello how are you?' and return it without spaces and punctuation, and in lower case like this 'hellohowareyou'. However when I run the code I get an error "string index out of range" on the 5th line. Please help.

```
  onlyLetters(' K KKdf afd')
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  IndexError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-368-70e5521e7134>          in <module>()
  ----> 1 onlyLetters(' K KKdf afd')

  <ipython-input-367-fb538af71ff5> in onlyLetters(seq)
        3     letter = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'z')
        4     for i in range(len(seq)):
  ----> 5         if seq[i] != letter:
        6             seq = seq[:i] + seq[i+1:]
        7     return seq

       IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Here is a hint, what do you think happens when `i` gets larger than `5`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're modifying the array while looping over it. This is usually a bad idea. I'd suggest instead copying the value into a new array when you see a letter you want rather than removing letters you don't want then returning the new array.

Comment: How am I modifying the tuple, can you elaborate? I thought by using the if statement I'm just checking if the parameter seq has a letter in it or not at the ith element. And if it doesn't then I slice it out, consequently modifying seq through concatenation of the seq before and after the ith element. Is this the wrong logic?

Comment: you're not modifying the tuple, you're modifying the string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `if seq[i] !=letter` you should do `if seq not in letter` you will get this corrected .

Then code looks like:

```
 def onlyLetters(seq):
        seq = seq.lower()
        letter = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'z')
        for i in range (len(seq)): 
            if seq not in letter:
                seq = seq[:i] + seq[i+1:]
        return seq
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same IndexError at the same line

Comment: I tried it once again just now,I think you should not get any error.

Comment: Where are you trying it?

Comment: try it in this [link](http://www.pythontutor.com/live.html#mode=edit) once